# Custom slider for elementor

Tags: wordpress, elementor

Is there any source/method to add slider in **#elementor** plug-in on wordPress for **free**?
**Note:** Elementor have their own slider but that wasn't free you have to buy it.

Comment: Sure there is. You can, for example, implement your own slider and learn how to integrate it with Elementor. This is one possible way to go about it: https://developers.elementor.com/creating-a-new-widget/

Comment: This is also a better way to create own widget but I already try that method unfortunately it is not suitable for the slider.

Comment: Fair enough. If you ever figure out a better way to create a custom slider for Elementor feel free to answer your own question. I'm sure future readers will appreciate it.

Comment: For custom slider in elementor we just have to install any slider plug-in like "slider 3". It will automatically appear on elementor's dashboard. No need of any codes just install and activate your slider plug-in .

Answer (score 0):

For custom slider in elementor we just have to install any slider plug-in like "slider 3". It will automatically appear on elementor's dashboard. No need of any codes just install and activate your slider plug-in.